Jakarta JMS Spring-boot sending messages immediately
I need send some messages without waiting transaction ending.
But all settings I tried like
 template.setSessionTransacted(false); and setting different acknowledge modes didn't bring any results.
There is jms libraries I use.
Now it use all settings default but I tried use all aknowledge mods enable end disable transaction mods
    implementation 'org.apache.activemq:artemis-jakarta-client:2.38.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.activemq:artemis-core-client:2.38.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.activemq:artemis-commons:2.38.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-jms:6.1.14'

My JMS Configuration
@Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(format("tcp://%s:%s", host, port));
        connectionFactory.setUser(user);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(pass);

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {

        Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.springframework.jms");
        logger.setLevel(Level.ERROR);

        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler());
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsAnycastTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
    }

Worker client code
    public static void doAllWork(int moduleId, MqProducer mqProducer, MqMessage message){
        mqProducer.sendAcceptToWork(moduleId, message);

        Work.doSomeWork(moduleId, mqProducer);

        mqProducer.sendEndWork(moduleId, message, 200L);
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    public static void doSomeWork(int moduleId, MqProducer mqProducer){

        int secToWork = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 10);
        LocalDateTime workstarted = LocalDateTime.now();

        while (Duration.between(workstarted, LocalDateTime.now()).getSeconds() < secToWork) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.printf("%s [api] WORK_ENDED message received%n", LocalDateTime.now());
            mqProducer.sendMessage("api", new MqMessage(IN_PROGRESS, moduleId, 200));
        }
    }

and there is output from worker client
sendAcceptToWork 3 0
2024-12-19T13:03:45.046627435 Working...
2024-12-19T13:03:46.057809869 Working...
2024-12-19T13:03:47.065647593 Working...
2024-12-19T13:03:48.074799444 Working...
2024-12-19T13:03:49.080706764 Working...
2024-12-19T13:03:50.088089181 Working...
2024-12-19T13:03:51.095799844 Working...
2024-12-19T13:03:52.104492990 Working...
2024-12-19T13:03:53.113162971 Working...
Work done

there is code api client
    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public void run(MqMessage message) {

        if (message.getMqOperationCode() == MqOperationCode.WORK_STARTED){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("%s [api] WORK_STARTED message received%n", LocalDateTime.now());
            return;
        }
        if (message.getMqOperationCode() == MqOperationCode.IN_PROGRESS){
            System.out.printf("%s [api] IN_PROGRESS message received%n", LocalDateTime.now());
            return;
        }
        if (message.getMqOperationCode() == MqOperationCode.WORK_ENDED){
            System.out.printf("%s [api] WORK_ENDED message received%n", LocalDateTime.now());
            return;
        }

        System.out.printf("%s [api] message received : \n%s%n", LocalDateTime.now(), message);
    }

and output in same iteration
2024-12-19T13:03:53.141036336 [api] WORK_STARTED message received
2024-12-19T13:03:53.146047337 [api] IN_PROGRESS message received
2024-12-19T13:03:53.150053390 [api] IN_PROGRESS message received
2024-12-19T13:03:53.153668788 [api] IN_PROGRESS message received
2024-12-19T13:03:53.157834576 [api] IN_PROGRESS message received
2024-12-19T13:03:53.161060836 [api] IN_PROGRESS message received
2024-12-19T13:03:53.163221293 [api] IN_PROGRESS message received
2024-12-19T13:03:53.165163888 [api] IN_PROGRESS message received
2024-12-19T13:03:53.166759323 [api] IN_PROGRESS message received
2024-12-19T13:03:53.168365120 [api] IN_PROGRESS message received
2024-12-19T13:03:53.169784977 [api] WORK_ENDED message received

As you can see worker client send all messages in one time, but I need to send each message without waiting transaction ending.

You can also try to check this Stackoverflow question.
And I think, you could also share mqProducer code.

I find how to do it
public void commit(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
        jmsTemplate.execute((SessionCallback<Void>) session -> {
            try {
                JmsUtils.commitIfNecessary(session);
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                log.warn("Sending to MQ failed");
            }
            return null;
        });
    }


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
